# How to start exe from asp application within IIS running with AD user privileges

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iis, printing, process

I have an ASP web application running IIS. The application identity is set to a specific user from the Active Directory (the same as I logged in to the pc).

I want to open a PDF file and print it. To achieve this, I use the following commands.

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = printer;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(10000);
```

I set full permission on the folder (which contains the PDF) for the user (which is set as the identity in IIS).

It works if I run it within Visual Studio, but doesn't if I deploy it to IIS (neither on the same pc). In case of the IIS, the Adobe Reader appears in the task manager, but only there, and doesn't print.

Has someone any ideas for this solution?

Comment: Does the server have a printer installed?

Comment: Of course, and it also works at the interop excel printing module.
But in this case, the PDF printing not works not only at the live server, but on my local machine too, if I deploy it to my local IIS. (also with the same IIS identity settings). In Visual Studio, it works fine, so the code is able to do the print process.

Comment: I suspect that Adobe Reader opens up, but has "questions". Running as a different user, it might miss a default printer, or default settings. 
It's probably standing there, waiting for input on a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Acrobat Reader doesn't support silent printing at all. Although there is a command line parameter to set running without UI, it didn't seem to work for me.

As I read many times, developers preferred to use some 3rd party libraries, or use Foxit Reader instead of Acrobat Reader.
I chose Foxit Reader. It's also a free PDF reader app, it can also be parameterized similar to Acrobat Reader, and it supports silent printing. This worked for me.